# Compare documents (images)

Tags: comparison, ocr

I need to compare a pdf with about 27000 pages (scanned pages) to another pdf with about 28000 pages (also scanned pages) so that I can find the 1000 pages which differ.

Does anyone now a good program to do this job?

Comment: What do you mean by equal pages? Are they the same scan? Or they have the same verbal content, but are are otherwise different images, like the same paper page shot from two different angles and/or in different conditions of light?

Comment: The content of the page are equal but the images are different (to different scans).

Comment: Then it's a difficult problem. In the past, for my wife, I looked at this, http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2012/09/comparing-scanned-documents-tips-and-workarounds/  with some results.  Not perfect, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Compare It!](http://www.grigsoft.com/wincmp3.htm/) is a nice tool, it can compare files of pretty much any type and find differences between the two. It should work for PDFs; I'm not sure if it would show up as the actual PDF or as code.

Comment: Are you the author of `Compare It!`?

Comment: Haha no. I just used it for a similar task to the one described above.